# Obtener datos de una tabla en un intervalo de hora especifica Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una consulta que me ha tomado gran parte del día. He visto tutoriales y cosas similares, pero no logro llegar.
Necesito obtener información que se ha cargado sólo en los últimos 5 minutos. No sé como poner esto en la Query, ya que estoy tomando toda la información del día.
Esta es mi Query. Agradecería de todo corazón su ayuda, gracias.

```
SELECT distinct CT.COD_CATEGORIA_ARCH, 
  CT.DESC_CATEGORIA_ARCH,
  FV.CORR_FICHA, 
  TF.COD_TIPO,DK.DIRECTORIO,
  FV.NRO_FICHA||'_'||FV.NOM_ARCHIVO as NOMBRE_ARCHIVO,
  FV.DESC_ARCHIVO, 
  FV.FEC_CARGA,
  FV.FECHA_VIGENCIA,
  FV.COD_ESTADO,
  SUC.NOM_SUC,
  F.RUT_CLI AS RUT_CLIENTE,
  CL.RAZON_SOCIAL,
  FV.NRO_FICHA,
  ESTADO_FICHA_VENTA(FV.NRO_FICHA,SYSDATE)||' - '||ES.DESC_ESTADO,
  ESTADO_FICHA_VENTA,
  (SYSDATE) FECHA_ESTADO_FICHA, TF.DESCRIPCION_TIPO AS SUBTIPO
FROM ANEXO_NUMERO_FICHAS FV, 
  FICHA_VENTA F, 
  DIR_KSA DK,
  TIPO_FICHA_ANEXOS TF,
  CLIENTE CL, SUCURSAL SUC,
  CATEGORIA_TIPO_ARCHIVOS CT,
  ESTADO ES
WHERE FV.NRO_FICHA = F.NRO_FICHA AND DK.COD_SISTEMA = FV.COD_SISTEMA 
  AND DK.COD_TIPO_DIR  = FV.COD_TIPO_DIR AND TF.COD_TIPO  = FV.COD_TIPO 
  AND F.RUT_CLI = CL.RUT_CLI
  AND F.COD_SUC = SUC.COD_SUC 
  AND TF.COD_CATEGORIA_ARCH = CT.COD_CATEGORIA_ARCH
  AND ESTADO_FICHA_VENTA(F.NRO_FICHA,SYSDATE) = ES.COD_ESTADO
  AND FV.COD_ESTADO = 1 /AND **FV.FEC_CARGA >= 
  TO_DATE('20210329','YYYYMMDD')**
ORDER BY FV.NRO_FICHA DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tu campo `FV.FEC_CARGA` sea de tipo timestap, tu consulta debería ser la siguiente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
...
FROM
...
AND
...
AND TO_DATE(FV.FEC_CARGA, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= SYSDATE - 5/(24*60)
```

Tienes que hacer una conversión de la fecha de tu tabla y decirle a sql que quieres los últimos 5 minutos, y eso es restando la fecha actual(SYSDATE) y dividiendo tu tiempo (5) entre el producto de las horas del día por los minutos que tiene una hora(60) => (24*60)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Estuve probando y jugando con lo que me ayudaste y no logro ejecutar bien. Me podrías ayudar ? Mi formato de Fv.Fec_Carga es asi  2021-03-29T10:25:54

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Y tu campo efectivamente es timestap.

Comment: Me aparece la tabla vacía. Cuando pongo editar el campo, me aparece seleccionar fecha y hora. No tengo visibilidad de la tabla mas que la consulta, ya que es externa y no me dieron los accesos para visualizar.

Comment: Es decir solo tienes acceso a la consola de comandos. No hay problema, si accedes al terminal del oracle, solo debes ejecutar la consulta tal cual.

Answer (score 0):

@gaidyjg Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Estuve probando y jugando con lo que me ayudaste y no logro ejecutar bien. Me podrías ayudar ? Mi formato de Fv.Fec_Carga es asi 2021-03-29T10:25:54